# How to catch error from QtMultimedia in Python?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I created application in PyQt + QtMultimedia that plays videos. When QtMultimedia can not find backend for playing videos (on Linux it's Gstreamer) it shows this error in terminal:

`defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"`

However PyQt doesn't throw exception so I can not catch it in python. Is there a way how to detect this error and show some warning to user?

Answer (score 1):

The warning is probably shown using `qWarning()`, so you should be able to use [`qInstallMessageHandler`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) (part of `PyQt5.QtCore` in PyQt) to catch them.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#mediaStatusChanged).

The problem you describle should be emitting the signal:

```
QMediaPlayer::mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus status)
```

where status = QMediaPlayer::ServiceMissingError

So, just connect a slot to that signal and manage it.

Comment: It's the [error](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#error-1) signal that would emit `ServiceMissingError`.